# how to find elements in array with reference of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to found the ids connection with the help of name connection

this are my container elements

```
  const TotalNodes = [ 
                             {id : 1, name : "apple"},
                             {id : 2 , name : "banana"},
                             {id : 3 , name : "orange"},
                             {id : 4 , name : "lamon"},
                             {id : 5 , name : "suger"},
                             {id : 6 , name : "salt"}
                          ]
```

this is my reference array

```
const NodesConnection = [
                            {source : "suger" , target : "salt"},
                            {source : "apple" , target : "orange"}
                          ]
```

**this is final output**

```
 const NodesConnectionWithIds = [
                                   {source : 5 , target : 6},
                                   {source : 1 , target : 3}
                                 ]
```

> **any help is so appreciatable**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that does the trick:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {{id: number, name: string}[]} nodes
 * @param {{source: string, target: string}[]} connections
 * @returns {{source: number, target: number}[]}
 */
function matchNodes(nodes, connections) {
  return connections.map((connection) => {
    const source = nodes.find((node) => node.name === connection.source);
    const target = nodes.find((node) => node.name === connection.target);
    return {
      source: source.id,
      target: target.id,
    };
  });
}

console.log(matchNodes(TotalNodes, NodesConnection));
```